# Can we inherit Ktable from parent class to child class?

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

We have a requirement to reuse KTable(Gender) in multiple classes by inheriting from parent class but when we create inheritance linkage then it shows an error **Topic has already been registered by another source** 
I am passing builder parameter from singleton object.
How could it can be possible in seperate two classes?

```
object app{

def main{
builder properties .....

new Parent(builder).test()
new child(builder).testing()
}
}


Class Parent(builder : StreamBuilder) {

val gender : KTable = ........
}


Class child(builder : StreamBuilder) extends Parent(builder){
gender.tostream.peek((k,v) => println(v))
}
```

Comment: Are you passing the same builder object around? Then the topolgies are the same, right?

Comment: As the error message indicated, you can read a single topic only once. (There is a ticket to actually lift this limitation: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-6687) What do you exactly try to achieve? It seems you have some miss-understanding how Kafka Streams works.